# Python searching for number of IPs in Apache log file

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for count the number of times IP addresses pop up in a standard apache log file, this is what I have so far but it always gives out zeroes:

```
def ips_in_log(log_name):
   with open(log_name, 'r') as f:
      log = f.read()
   ipcount = log.count(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$')
   print(ipcount)
```

Here is a sample line from the log file:

```
137.43.92.119 - - [04/Feb/2013:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /node/feed 
HTTP/1.0" 200 47208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;    
rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3"
```

Comment: If I replace the regex with say r'Firefox' it'll tell me how many times the word Firefox is in the log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not to pass a regex to `count` function,be cause the `count` function accept a string as argument and look for it within your text and when you pass `r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$'` it assumes it as a row string.

Instead you can use `re.findall` to find all of matches then use `len` function to get the count of ip's:

*Edit* : also remove the anchor `$` ant the trailing of your regex.

```
def ips_in_log(log_name):
   with open(log_name, 'r') as f:
      log = f.read()
   ipcount = len(re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}',log))
   print(ipcount)
```

And if you just want the length as an alternative way you can use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) that Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances.

```
def ips_in_log(log_name):
   with open(log_name, 'r') as f:
      log = f.read()
   ipcount = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}',log))
   print(ipcount)
```

Comment: I tried this, however it gives me the error:
TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: still the same error :/
And with the changed first findall part if gives the error SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Comment: @Scy sorry it has a syntax error! i edit the answer! try it now surely it'll work!

Comment: @Scy Maybe your regex is wrong and it doesnt match any thing, can you add some line of your string to your question?

Comment: @Kasra Note the `$`. I call that out in my answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thank you so much! This works! And thank you Kesra too! ^_^

Comment: @Scy Jonathan is wrote you need to remove the anchor `$`!

Answer (score 2):

The `$` at the end of your regex matches only the last character in the input. So you will match 0 from this input:

> 1.1.1.1 blah 2.2.2.2 
>   bleck 3.3.3.3 blee

If you're expecting to count IP addresses in the middle of your input you'll need to change your regex:

```
ipcount = len(re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', log))
```